# Serverside WebKit with node.js

Tags: node.js, webkit

In my node.js app I need to render an HTML5 page on server side and make it's screenshot. Are there any libraries to do this?

Comment: I downvoted your question for lack of any research effort by searching the web.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if people could find answer directly on StackOverflow? What's the problem asking question here while I'm doing my own research?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97880/is-lack-of-other-research-a-reason-to-downvote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) which is based on [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).